# How to create another scene in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, view

I made a tab bar controller and it has 2 views, I want to add another that will be in there also. I also want a intro scene that pops up before you get to tab bar options as a sort of introduction to the app.

Comment: What did you tried? How did you build the 2 tabs view...

Comment: the tab bar was made with the tab bar item in objects but when i try to add another tab bar item into my tab bar it dosent work

Comment: What are you using? SwitUI? storyboard? etc.

Comment: Im using storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the template "Tabbed App" then get into the Library. Drag'n'drop a "View Controller" into the storyboard graphical view. Then ctrl-click on the "Tab-Bar Controller" object and pull a link to the newly added "View Controller", then use the "Relationship segue" named "view controllers". That's all.

Comment: i dont think im using that template, i tried it and the blue link showed up but it couldn't connect to the newly added view controller.

Comment: @SammyHasan then something is incomplete in your problem description. Adding a tab should be very easy. Not sure to be able to help you more.

Comment: ahh i finally got it, i was pulling ctrl-clicking tab bar and not the tab bar controller. Thanks man